# Search a string for multiple letters at once

Tags: java, string, search, indexof

I need to search a string for vowels at the end of a four letter word. I could do an if-else tree and search each letter individually, but I would like to simplify.

You generally search for a letter by this way:

```
String s = four
if (s.indexOf ('i') = 4)
  System.out.println("Found");
else
  System.out.println("Not found");
```

Could I instead replace the parameter of the `indexOf` with this:

```
s.indexOf ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

It would make everything a lot easier.

Unfortunately, I cannot use Regexp classes, and I'm required to only use things we have previously learned.

Comment: one type: `s.indexOf ('i') == 4` - note the `==`

Comment: So which index you are expecting to return ?

Comment: You might want to take a closer look into regex: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: Just build your function... takes an array as argument, and returns an array of indexes (found with the code you suggested) for each of the element in the input array.

Comment: `s.lastIndexOf('i') == 3` would be correct for "kind" (false) and especially "hihi" (true) as counted from 0. `"aeiou".indexOf`? `s.charAt(3)`?

Answer (score 3):

Regex?  I believe this works.  "Any 3 word characters followed by a e i or u."

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w{3}[aeiou]?");
    String test = "mike";
    System.out.println("matches? " + p.matcher(test).matches());
```

Well, if you can't use regex, then use why not something like EDIT:  Modified to be inline with GaborSch's answer -- my alternate algorithm was very close, but the use of the char instead of creating another string is WAY better! Give an upvote to GaborSch!)

```
    if(someString.length() == 4){
        char c = someString.charAt(3);

        if("aeiou".indexOf(c) != -1){
             System.out.println("Gotcha ya!!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is for a class and im required to only use things we have previously learned and we have not reached that yet. Thank you for the answer though!

Comment: @user3033159 Have you learned arrays and for loops, because that is another way of doing it. Also you should tag it homework if it was for class.

Comment: Or have you learned the `String` methods, including `matches(String)`?

Comment: i cant use arrays which is annoying me because it would be good for my assignment, but how would use a for statement this way?

Comment: @user3033159 You can use the String method `charAt(int)` to access an individual character of your String.

Comment: Would be better: if("aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(c) != -1)

Comment: @SajalDutta Yep!  Already changed it and gave credit to GaborSch.

Answer (score 3):

```
String s = "FOUR"; // A sample string to look into
String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"; // Vowels in both cases

if(vowels.indexOf(s.charAt(3)) >= 0){ // The last letter in a four-letter word is at index 4 - 1 = 3
    System.out.println("Found!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Found!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
char c = s.charAt(3);
if("aeiou".indexOf(c) >= 0) {
    System.out.println("Found");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

The trick is that you pick the 4th character and search for it **in the String of all vowels**.

This is a Regexp-free one-liner solution.

Comment: Should be s.charAt(3) as it's a four-letter word.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for [`String#matches(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) and a suiting regular expression:

```
if (s.matches(".*[aeiou]$")) {
    /* s ends with a vowel */
}
```

If using regular expressions is not allowed you could define a function for this:

```
static boolean endsWithVowel(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {  /* nothing or empty string has no vowels */
        return false;
    }
    return "aeiou".contains(str)             /* str is only vowels */
        || endsWithVowel(str.substring(1));  /* or rest of str is only vowels */
}
```